# Svcutil change ItemChoiceType number after generate the same xsd

Tags: c#, .net, svcutil.exe

I use svcutil.exe (or dotnet-svcutil in newer projects) for generate service API from xsd and wsdl. The `choice` element in the xsd generate `ItemChoiceType` in the generated classes.

If I used more `choice` elements in xsd, svcutil generate `ItemChoiceType`, `ItemChoiceType1`, `ItemChoiceType2` etc.

But when I regenerate API, sometimes the numbering of `ItemChoiceType` is changed. If I use some assignment of `ItemChoiceType` in code, the code couldn't be translated, because it is another type.

Is there an option to keep numbering? Thanks

Comment: Why are you creating a schema for some types instead of using all the types?  This way you only have to generate one xsd instead of regenerating the xsd multiple times.

Comment: I generate all types at one moment but when I do some changes in xsd then I need to regenerate service API. The change could be new independetnt element/attribute only and the ```ItemChoiceType``` has got new number (become another type)

Comment: Are all the schemas using the same version?  If you are using the same main schema and just choosing to create classes for specific elements the numbering should not change.  The schema contains types which are properties in one or more other types.  The ordering when a type is more than once is dependent on the order they appear in the schema. if the types were an enumeration than the value should not change.

Comment: In the xsd is not defined schema version so it should be the same. It seems like svcutil using parallelism and ordering depends on race condition.